# Backbone - Getting raw response from server

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

How do I get the raw response returned by the server when using POST/DELETE methods in Backbone (so you can't get the raw response in `fetch`/`parse` like GET)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the `responseText` from the server when the ajax call is complete.

The `save`, `fetch`, etc methods from Backbone provide the jQuery promise generated by the call to `$.ajax`.

When this promise has been resolved (e.g. the transaction is complete), you'll have access to the `responseText` property on the promise.

```
var promise = a_model.save();
$.when(promise).then(function(){
    console.log(promise.responseText); // if you're getting XML back it's `responseXML`
});
```

Here's the [jQuery docs on the jqXHR object](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR) which is the promise object you get.

Additionally `$.when` and `.then` are described in the [Deferred object documentation](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/)

Answer (score -2):

Why don't you just use the network tab in Chrome developer tools? That's the easiest way of viewing your raw requests and responses. Plus it is laid out in an easy to view format, showing cookies, timing values etc...

Comment: I actually think it's quite ambiguous what their asking - and this is compounded by their poor grammar and phrasing of the question. My answer does supply a way of getting the response text (although this admittedly depends on how you define the word 'get'), so I think your down vote is unfair.

Comment: I didn't down vote you.  I left a comment explaining why I was leaving a second answer.  Down votes on correct answers (your answer is correct for an interpretation of the question) are just dumb.

Comment: ah ok sorry - my bad, but yeah whoever down voted is a dumbass