# jQuery Promises and Backbone

Tags: backbone.js, promise

I found this snippet of code that does what I want it to:

```
var promise = this.model.save();
$.when(promise).then(function() {
     console.log(promise.responseText);
});
```

I want to get back the `responseText` from my Backbone call to `this.model.save()`.  This code was documented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12795489/backbone-getting-raw-response-from-server).  But it's not logging anything, even if I pull a raw text string in the `console.log()` call.

Could someone please explain in layman's terms what a jQuery promise is?  I've read about them, but I don't think I quite got what they were.  That might help me understand why this code isn't working for me.  If I `console.log(promise)` in between the first and second lines of code, then I get the `responseText`.  So something is happening in either the `$.when` or the `then` that is causing this to go wrong.

EDIT:

After reading the article, I discovered I could do this:

```
var promise = this.model.save(); 
$.when(promise).then(null, function(obj) {
    console.log(obj.responseText);
});
```

But I don't understand what the `null` represents.  `then` seems to take two parameters, a success function and a failure function.  But wouldn't the success function be first?  I get a 200 response from the server.

Comment: read this http://css.dzone.com/articles/exploring-deferred-and-promise

Comment: It looks like a good article.  Thanks.

Comment: no probs :) happy reading..

Answer (score 28, accepted):

So first off, I'm pretty sure you don't need the `when` part; from the jQuery docs:

> The jqXHR objects returned by $.ajax() as of jQuery 1.5 implement the
>   Promise interface, giving them all the properties, methods, and
>   behavior of a Promise (see Deferred object for more information).

Since Promise has a `then` method already, you can just do:

```
this.model.save().then(null, function(obj) {
    console.log(obj.responseText);
});
```

(The fact that the above code almost reads like an English sentence is a major advantage of using Deferreds, for me at least.)

As for your `null` argument, the docs are again pretty clear.  There are three signatures for `then` (and that's just to cover the different jQuery versions; any given version has less):

> deferred.then( doneFilter [, failFilter ] [, progressFilter ] )
>
> deferred.then( doneCallbacks, failCallbacks )
>
> deferred.then( doneCallbacks, failCallbacks [, progressCallbacks ] )

As you can see, all three take the "done" function first, and the failure function second.  This does seem to imply that you're getting a failure, which is confusing.  One way to avoid the problem is to not use `then` at all.  Instead, try the following:

```
this.model.save().always(function(obj) {
    console.log(obj.responseText);
});
```

That will make your function get called no matter what happens.  However, you probably should figure out what's going on, so you might want to instead add a success and failure callback to do some debugging:

```
this.model.save().done(function() {
    // Success case
}).fail(function() {
    // Failure case
});
```

Comment: What are the advantages of using jquery's deferred instead of the plain backbone callbacks, like these?

`this.model.save({success:function(){

},error:function(){

}});`

Comment: It's just style really.  If you're doing complex things (like say making two AJAX calls, where the second one needs data that comes back from the first one) then the Deferred style lets you do that very elegantly.  Otherwise though it's really just a matter of how you want to style your code.  And really this isn't even a Backbone-specific issue; in just plain old jQuery you also have `$.ajax({success: handler});` vs, `$.ajax({}).done(handler)` to choose from.

Comment: @machineghost.  Thank you for your very thorough response.  This explains a lot.

Answer (score 7):

Because `this.model.save` returns a promise, you can do the following instead:

```
this.model.save()
    .done(function(response) {
        console.log("Success!");
    })
    .fail(function(response) {
        console.log("Error!");
    });
```

(That's easier than the whole `$.when` bit.)

My guess is that although your response is returning a 200 code, it is still "failing" because the response data type doesn't match up with what you're expecting (what's set in the `dataType` attribute in the `$.ajax` call).

Answer (score 0):

I am a big fan of using promise, and I think the promise means very similar things in different packages.

To answer your question, which previous answers didn't, the "then" function is a function of a promise, the "when" function is a fail-save, incase the object is not a promise, a "when(obj)" will make sure it is a promise, so that you can use the elegant xxx.then(success(){},error(){}).

btw, the "deferred" that machineghost said is the package that let you use promise. 
For starting to know promise and how to use it. check out this tutorial. It explains every thing very clearly, it is the article that made me so into promises. 
http://strongloop.com/strongblog/promises-in-node-js-with-q-an-alternative-to-callbacks/

Now, as machineghost said, it seems your sync call is getting an error, according to a REST API documentation,https://parse.com/docs/rest# (don't know if it is the same as backbone), the server will response a JSON object for a "create" request in this format:

```
{"createdAt": "2011-08-20T02:06:57.931Z","objectId": "Ed1nuqPvcm"}
```

My guess is, maybe your server did not respond the request with the correct JSON, so the save() think the operation failed because there was no "createAt" field, event thought your sever did created the item.